# Bounty offered on another person's question changes scope of Original Question

Tags: discussion, scope, bounty

Large Bounty offered by someone on another person's question.

[CRM16 - Trigger custom action from WebApi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41828266/crm16-trigger-custom-action-from-webapi)

Question is answered based on the scope of the OP.

Bounty sponsor adds comment on OP making a request that changes the scope of the OP.

How does one deal with a situation like that?

Comment: Mind showing us the bounty?  If it's particularly bad the consensus would be to flag a moderator since they're the only ones that can do anything about it, but I'm sure we'd still like to see.

Comment: "Looking for C# sample" on VB.Net question indeed feels strange. The request can be interpreted as paid code translation from one language to another and hence off-topic... on other hand we have other questions that includes both VB.Net and C# variants (like famous NRE one) - so question may become canonical .Net answer as result of this bounty.